# Отображение русских комментариев к коду в GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, кириллица

Помогите разобраться. Я пушу 2 файла в репозиторий .cpp и .h - в них какой-то код и комментарии с русскими символами. GitLab в .cpp файле всё отображает корректно, но в .h файле русские символы или вообще не отображаются или пишется какая-то фигня.

Вот, например, код в .h файле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так он в GitLab отображается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В git bash я настроил Locale: ru_RU, Character set: UTF-8, не помогло. Причём в GitHub это помогло, но там уже была проблема в .c файлах.

Я пробовал менять значения у параметров репозитория в config: commitencoding и logoutputencoding на cp1251 или utf-8, и всё равно ничего не менялось.

В чём проблема?

Comment: *"Я пробовал менять значения у параметров репозитория в config: commitencoding и logoutputencoding на cp1251 или utf-8"* - ¿что значит "или"? ¿В какой кодировке исходники?

Comment: Я вот так смотрел (кодировка по умолчанию, utf-8, как я понимаю):
$ git log --pretty="%h [%e]" и вывод: 96f12b8 []

Comment: Кодировка файлов - это то, как они сохраняются в текстовом редокторе. Вывод git log не при чем.

Comment: Файл .h: C source, ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators. А файл .cpp: Unicode text, UTF-8 (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators. Видно, что кодировка у .h файла не utf-8, но как её изменить?

Comment: Всё, проблема решена. В Notepad++ я перекодировал файл в utf-8 и теперь в gitlab он корректно отображается. Почему-то MS Visual Studio так файлы кодирует, это нельзя в нём изменить, чтобы в будущем не приходилось в Notepad всё менять? А то я в нём не нашёл этого раздела, в Notepad прям на панели раздел "кодирование"

Comment: Поставьте себе расширение https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=genrwoody.FileEncodingVS2022 или https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qazwsxlty.forceutf8withbom2022

Answer (score 1):

На gitlab'е уже много лет висит баг-репорт с просьбой поддержки win-1251

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15046

Единственный способ — держать исходники в utf-8.

Можно также настроить, чтоб они локально преобразовывались в нужную кодировку через `.gitattributes`, но это поддерживается не всеми клиентами git.

Comment: Перекодирование файла в utf-8 помогло. Но когда я создал файл .gitattributes и написал там: *.h text, то русские символы всё равно не отображались.